# PHP update database field without redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, codeigniter

I'm using PHP Codeigniter. I have a sidebar in my website that displays every task I have in my database. In the Task table, I have a text column, that I want to be able to update when pressing enter.

[image: The textarea that I want to use to update]

What I did at the moment was to create a javascript function that gets called when pressing Enter :

```
function CursorKeyDown(e, id){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        var text = document.getElementById('area').value;
        window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('task/Task/validSuivi/')?>" + '/' + id + '/' + text;
        //window.history.pushState('', '', "<?php echo site_url('task/Task/validSuivi/')?>" + '/' + id + '/' + text);
        //alert("Enter was pressed was presses");
    }

    return false;
}
```

At the moment if I use window.location.href, it redirects to the link or where my controller wants it. What I want is to call the method, update the database, but no redirection or whatever. Is that possible ? With Ajax ? I tried something with pushstate but it just modifies the URL without triggering the method.

My method in the controller :

```
public function validSuivi($id_tache, $text)
{
    $arr['suivi'] = $text;

    $this->task_model->update(array('id_tache'=>$id_tache),$arr);

    //redirect('task/task');
}
```

Comment: are you using jquery ?

Comment: @RanjeetSingh jQuery is tagged.

Comment: you can make an ajax request in your function to save data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code :-

```
<script>
function CursorKeyDown(e, id){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        var text = document.getElementById('area').value;
        var ajax_url = "<?php echo site_url('task/Task/validSuivi/');?>" + '/' + id + '/' + text
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {},
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('get your response..');
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(a,b,c) {
                console.log('error');
            },
            beforeSend:function(jqXHR, plain_jqXHR) {
                console.log('show some loading..');
                console.log('disable button..');
            },
            complete: function() {
                console.log('hide loading..');
                console.log('enable button..');
            }
        }); 
    }
    return false;
}

</script>
```

if your response not of **json** comment **dataType: "json"** in ajax request.

Comment: mine pleasure. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need ajax to do that :), this code should work :

**Javascript**

```
function CursorKeyDown(e, id){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        var text = document.getElementById('area').value;
        $.get("<?php echo site_url('task/Task/validSuivi/')?>" + '/' + id + '/' + text, function() {
            alert("Enter was pressed was presses and saved to database");
        })
    }

    return false;
}
```

Do not forget to send a response on your controller, for instance, returning error: true if the record updated succesfully and false if not :

**PHP**

```
public function validSuivi($id_tache, $text)
{
    $arr['suivi'] = $text;

    $this->task_model->update(array('id_tache'=>$id_tache),$arr);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['error' => false]);
}
```